# UITableView loading wrong prototype cell from storyboard

Tags: uitableview, uistoryboard

I am having a really weird error that I cannot figure out, I really need some help right now. Basically, the tableView has three UITableViewCell subclasses that have their own prototype cell, and appear in their own section. But the prototype that is in the third section is also appearing in the second section. The weird part is that after putting some NSLogs into my code, the cell that is showing up in the second section section (which should be in the third section) is the correct subclass of UITableViewCell, but the content from the other prototype is showing up. I have no idea why this is happening. I have check to make sure the prototypes are of the right subclass, and the identifiers are all correct, and they are. Has anyone encountered this problem before? Sorry in advance for how long my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    WaveDetailCell *waveDetails;
    ActionsCell *actions;
    CommentCell *comments;
    id cellToReturn;

    if (self.hasAgrees || self.hasComments)
    {
        switch (indexPath.section)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                waveDetails = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:WaveDetailCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

                if ([waveDetails.waveLabel respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)])
                {
                    NSString *name = self.currentWaveObject.wavedToUserID;
                    NSString *fullWaveString = [name stringByAppendingString:self.currentWaveObject.waveString];
                    NSRange range = [fullWaveString rangeOfString:self.currentWaveObject.wavedToUserID];
                    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:HelveticaMedium size:16.0f];
                    NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
                    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:fullWaveString];
                    [attributedString addAttributes:attrs range:range];
                    [waveDetails.waveLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
                }

                waveDetails.wavedByNameLabel.text = self.currentWaveObject.wavedByUserID;
                waveDetails.timestampLabel.text = self.currentWaveObject.creationDate;

                //round the corners of the imageview
                [self setCornerRadiusForImageView:waveDetails.profilePicImageView withRadius:CGSizeMake(4.0f, 4.0f)];
                [self setCornerRadiusForImageView:waveDetails.waverProfileImageView withRadius:CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f)];
                cellToReturn = waveDetails;
            }
                break;

            case 1:
            {
                if (self.hasAgrees)
                {
                    //create agrees cell
                }
                else
                {
                    actions = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ActionsCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
                    cellToReturn = actions;
                }
            }

            case 2:
            {
                if (self.hasAgrees)
                {
                    //if there are agrees, and no comments, then the last section should be the actions cell
                    actions = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ActionsCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
                    cellToReturn = actions;
                }
                else
                {
                    //there are comments, and no agrees
                    comments = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CommentCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
                    CommentObject *comment = [self.currentWaveObject.commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    comments.userNameLabel.text = comment.commenterID;
                    comments.commentLabel.text = comment.commentText;
                    comments.timeStampLabel.text = comment.timeStamp;
                    [self setCornerRadiusForImageView:comments.userImageView withRadius:CGSizeMake(3.0f, 3.0f)];
                    cellToReturn = comments;
                }
            }

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (self.hasComments && self.hasAgrees)
    {
        switch (indexPath.section)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                waveDetails = (WaveDetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:WaveDetailCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

                if ([waveDetails.waveLabel respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)])
                {
                    NSString *name = self.currentWaveObject.wavedToUserID;
                    NSString *fullWaveString = [name stringByAppendingString:self.currentWaveObject.waveString];
                    NSRange range = [fullWaveString rangeOfString:self.currentWaveObject.wavedToUserID];
                    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:HelveticaMedium size:16.0f];
                    NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
                    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:fullWaveString];
                    [attributedString addAttributes:attrs range:range];
                    [waveDetails.waveLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
                }

                waveDetails.wavedByNameLabel.text = self.currentWaveObject.wavedByUserID;
                waveDetails.timestampLabel.text = self.currentWaveObject.creationDate;

                //round the corners of the imageview
                [self setCornerRadiusForImageView:waveDetails.profilePicImageView withRadius:CGSizeMake(4.0f, 4.0f)];
                [self setCornerRadiusForImageView:waveDetails.waverProfileImageView withRadius:CGSizeMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
                cellToReturn = waveDetails;
            }
                break;

            case 1:
            {
                //create agrees cell
            }
                break;

            case 2:
            {
                actions = (ActionsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ActionsCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
                cellToReturn = actions;
            }
                break;

            case 3:
            {
                comments = (CommentCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CommentCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
                CommentObject *comment = [self.currentWaveObject.commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                comments.userNameLabel.text = comment.commenterID;
                comments.commentLabel.text = comment.commentText;
                comments.timeStampLabel.text = comment.timeStamp;
                [self setCornerRadiusForImageView:comments.userImageView withRadius:CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f)];
                cellToReturn = comments;
            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            waveDetails = (WaveDetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:WaveDetailCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            if ([waveDetails.waveLabel respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)])
            {
                NSString *name = self.currentWaveObject.wavedToUserID;
                NSString *fullWaveString = [name stringByAppendingString:self.currentWaveObject.waveString];
                NSRange range = [fullWaveString rangeOfString:self.currentWaveObject.wavedToUserID];
                UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:HelveticaMedium size:16.0f];
                NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
                NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:fullWaveString];
                [attributedString addAttributes:attrs range:range];
                [waveDetails.waveLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
            }

            waveDetails.wavedByNameLabel.text = self.currentWaveObject.wavedByUserID;
            waveDetails.timestampLabel.text = self.currentWaveObject.creationDate;

            //round the corners of the imageviews
            [self setCornerRadiusForImageView:waveDetails.profilePicImageView withRadius:CGSizeMake(4.0f, 4.0f)];
            [self setCornerRadiusForImageView:waveDetails.waverProfileImageView withRadius:CGSizeMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
            cellToReturn = waveDetails;
        }
        else
        {
            actions = (ActionsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ActionsCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cellToReturn = actions;
        }
    }
    return cellToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait, I figured it out. This is embarrassing, but I forgot a `break` in one of the cases in the switch statement!